# "Make a contact with" and "make a call to"

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

Between **Make a contact with...** and **make a call to...**, is there a difference?

Suppose I want to phone my friend (Lisa). Are these sentences below correct?

1. I want to make a contact with Lisa.
2. I want to make a call to Lisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

---

I want to make a contact with Lisa. This is not normally used in casual conversation but would be used in a more formal statement (discussed below)

**contact; verb**; to communicate with someone by calling or sending them a letter, email, etc.: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contact)

> I want to contact Lisa.

*This is just a general statement you wish to connect with Lisa. How we make contact is neither defined or important*.

In casual use we would not normally say make and we do not use the article "a" also with is not required.

NB. Articles are words that define a noun as specific or unspecific.

However if we wanted to establish more formal or regular communications with Lisa, we could say

> I want to make contact with Lisa.

*This means you wish to establish regular communication with someone*

**contact;** noun; (COMMUNICATION); communication with someone, especially by speaking or writing to them regularly: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contact)

> I want to make contact with The Secretary General

Meaning, *I want to open a channel of communications with The Secretary General*

---

This sentence is correct as it stands

> I want to make a call to Lisa.

*It means you wish to make a telephone call to Lisa.*

call verb (PHONE); to use a phone to talk to someone: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call?q=CALL)